# Synonyms for "tête-à-tête"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for *single word* synonyms for *tête-à-tête*, which express the idea of a private and intimate conversation. I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: The online thesaurus has an [entry for tête-à-tête](http://thesaurus.com/browse/t%C3%AAte-%C3%A0-t%C3%AAte?s=t).

Comment: Thanks @coleopterist for the edits. The online thesaurus did indeed have synonyms. As mentioned, however, I was looking for a single word synonym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the entries found in the [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/t%C3%AAte-%C3%A0-t%C3%AAte?s=t), I might suggest:

- **face-to-face**

Even though *face-to-face* is often used as an adjective (as in *face-to-face meeting*, *face-to-face interview*, or *face-to-face instruction*), *face-to-face* can also be used as a noun, meaning, well, *tête-à-tête*.  [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/face-to-face) defines *face-to-face* as:

> A meeting, especially a meeting between two people conducted in person as opposed to a meeting conducted at a distance through technology.

Moreover, [Google books](http://www.google.com/#q=%22have+a+face-to-face+with%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=-zWWUJOALOrXyAGcxoDQCA&ved=0CA0Q_AUoAA&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=5025d1f0ac3082a6&bpcl=37189454&biw=1554&bih=863) shows the expression used as a noun, in instances such as:

> Baretta needs to have a [face to face](http://books.google.com/books?id=fbs4rg2hIsQC&pg=PA123&dq=%22have%20a%20face-to-face%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IjaWUJnlHaf6yQHlu4H4Bg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22have%20a%20face-to-face%20with%22&f=false) with Robert and see that he has moved on...
>
> Adelman suggested that we have a [face-to-face](http://books.google.com/books?id=uDQYw_Dr-hEC&pg=PA162&dq=%22have%20a%20face-to-face%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IjaWUJnlHaf6yQHlu4H4Bg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22have%20a%20face-to-face%20with%22&f=false) with Jones, which we did.
>
> In an unprecedented move, Clifford went to Chicago to have a [face-to-face](http://books.google.com/books?id=s1pKI3mWpeAC&pg=PA192&dq=%22have%20a%20face-to-face%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hDeWUNeeAZTUyQH7noBo&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=%22have%20a%20face-to-face%20with%22&f=false) with Tony's superiors.

One other suggestion I might offer – particularly if you want to stress the *intimacy* of the conversation – is

- **pillow talk**

[OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=pillow%20talk&ls=a) lists this definition:

> intimate conversation between lovers (typically occurring in bed)

Comment: Single word request ;)

Comment: @mplungjan: Touché. :^) Still, if it gets its own entry in the [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pillow-talk), I consider that to fit the single-word-request bill. (The O.P. is free to disagree, of course.)

Comment: +1 _Let's have a "face-to-face" sometime soon_ is perfectly reasonable and a single word synonym for tête-à-tête. Just because thesaurus.com lists it as "face-to-face chat" doesn't mean that one cannot noun the adjective.

Comment: Yeah - like Let's have a t-a-t is one word too...

Comment: You can always verb the noun and say "**Let's face-to-face** tomorrow night". MS Word tells me that _face-to-face_ is only 1 word. In "_Let's interact_", _interact_ is only one word with the same number of syllables as _face-to-face_, so I don't think there's any significant difference between using a fused lexeme (_inter_ + _act_) and a hyphenated lexeme (_face-to-face_). Peevish pedantry is like sooooooooooooooooooooo passé, mplungjan. Please get over it and deal with the question rather than your sense of violated values. My judgments reflect my biases, not the absolute truth. And yours?

Comment: Thanks @J.R. While I was looking for a single word in the non-hyphenated sense, you're right that this does fit the bill, and hence, accepting.

Comment: @user21497 I've never seen a 'hyphenated word' have its 'single-wordness' disputed. But we really do need to tighten up on terms, so that say the equivalent compound nouns 'particle board', 'particle-board' and 'particleboard' are all termed (single) lexemes.

Answer (score 1):

*Confabulation*, which can be shortened to the informal *confab*.

Comment: It does not seem to be regarded as a synonym to T-a-T by the online thesauri.

Comment: Thanks Barrie. Interesting word ans suggestion, but I'm letting it pass for the negative connotation of fabricating lies to fill gaps in the memory.

Comment: Actually, "confab" is an excellent suggestion -- it fits the meaning of *tête-à-tête* almost exactly and would be well-understood in the US.  "Confabulation" is, alas, a poor choice, since it's most commonly used in the psychiatric sense to mean an imagined event.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try *huddle*, unless the sports metaphor isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Huddle isn't exactly the word I was looking for as I was looking for something between two people, but I like it, and might end up using it.

Comment: Two people **can** have a huddle. It is, actually, one of those words that has an oblique romantic connotation. And it rhymes with **cuddle**. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The normal English equivalent is [heart-to-heart](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=heart+to+heart&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=NHuWUM2WEJCk0AXDwoHACA&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3f622645d8196b60&bpcl=37189454&biw=1464&bih=917) *- an intimate talk in private; "he took me aside for a little heart-to-heart"*.

Unlike *tete-a-tete*, *heart-to-heart* is [often followed by the word "talk"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22heart%20to%20heart%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20heart%20to%20heart%20talk%22&oq=%22a%20heart%20to%20heart%20talk%22&gs_l=serp.3...11559.12701.1.13147.5.5.0.0.0.2.696.1308.2j1j0j1j0j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.pvl3PEeJYi4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6744cf75155b6f67&bpcl=37189454&biw=1464&bih=917).

---

I don't use it myself, but for an undeniably "single word" alternative, there's [schmooze](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=schmooze&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=n32WUPShDKbP0QXtqIDQCA&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3f622645d8196b60&bpcl=37189454&biw=1464&bih=917) ***verb***: to talk intimately and cozily; gossip. **noun**: a long and intimate conversation. Some may feel this word *always* implies *...in order to manipulate, flatter, or impress someone*.

Comment: Thanks @fumblefingers. I like heart-to-heart, but I think face-to-face fits tete-a-tete as a synonym better. Schmooze, as you say, has a negative connotation, at least for me.

Comment: @ak86: If you're happy with "face-to-face" that's your choice, I guess. But I'm surprised others are voting in that direction, since the primary sense of "face-to-face" is *interact **in person** (not, for example, on the telephone)*. You'll find it's very often used as an adjective, followed by "formal/business" words like *meeting, interview, environment*. Unlike "heart-to-heart" (which *always* implies "intimacy/privacy/honesty"), and more often either stands alone as a noun itself, or modifies words like *chat, talk, conversation*.

Comment: A late comment, but I find in *conversation* (rather than print), "heart-to-heart" is not followed by "talk". It may be regional, however.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'formal meeting' or 'personal meeting' instead of *face-to-face*; as *face to face* sounds very confrontational.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Gerard . We appreciate your input. We also appreciate links to sources where applicable. :)

Comment: I'd say there's only a faint hint of a confrontational encounter: see FF's 'comment'(!) above.

Comment: Not as confrontational as "head-to-head", which is another option.

Answer (score -1):

How about *surreptitious* or *covert*?

Comment: Thanks @Mottie, but I don't think either of them are a synonym to tete-a-tete as there's no secret talks.

Answer (score -1):

*Mano a mano* might be an alternative, but obviously only in an all male setting and neither does it possess the hush-hush quality you are looking for.